# ReactJS/JS/Firebase - Image Upload to Firebase Storage - ERRORS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase-storage

I have watched every tutorial and all done all the research possible, yet I keep getting errors for my code. An example error (this error keeps occurring for different part of the code)
[image]

In the same file I import `import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'` add then `const storage = firebase.storage()`, in a different file I also import `import firebase, {initializeApp} from "firebase/compat/app"; import "firebase/compat/auth"; import "firebase/compat/firestore";` I also tried to import `firebase/storage` but I had the same problem. Any help would be nice, thank you in advance :)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the import `firebase/storage` should be like this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";

// After you import app...
import "firebase/compat/storage";
```

You may refer to this documentation about [compat libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#:%7E:text=9.9.2-,Update%20imports%20to%20v9%20compat,-In%20order%20to).

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried this, but I guess not, I simply just imported storage in the firebase.js file with all the other imports and initialized it with ```const storage = app.storage();```